# Android cursor showing just the first item of the array

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-cursor

I can't find why my list doesn't print all of the items, it is printing only the first one, I checked my database and there is three items there, but this is what my log says:

```
10-03 14:46:07.116      833-833/br.com. I/System.out﹕ Q2: SELECT * FROM enderecos WHERE enderecos_id = 3
10-03 14:46:07.117      833-833/br.com. I/System.out﹕ END: Rua ujhuo
10-03 14:46:07.124      833-833/br.com. I/System.out﹕ Q2: SELECT * FROM telefones WHERE telefones_id = 5
10-03 14:46:07.125      833-833/br.com. I/System.out﹕ LIsta De TELEFone [br.com.database.models.TelefoneModel@422e8d58]
```

TelefoneModel@422e8d58 - this is the first one, the others are not showing.

Function:

```
   public List<TelefoneModel> getTelefonesDoCliente(Integer clientes_id) throws SQLException {    
        String query1 = "SELECT * FROM " + tabelaCLIENTES_HAS_TELEFONES + " WHERE " + ClienteHasTelefoneModel.Coluna.CLIENTES_ID + " = " + clientes_id;
        Cursor mCursor1 = bd.rawQuery(query1, null);

        List<TelefoneModel> listaDeRegistros = new ArrayList<TelefoneModel>();

        if (mCursor1.getCount() > 0) {    
            if (mCursor1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Integer TelefoneId = mCursor1.getInt(mCursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("telefones_id"));

                    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tabelaTELEFONES + " WHERE " + TelefoneModel.Coluna.TELEFONES_ID + " = " + TelefoneId;
                    System.out.println("Q2: " + query);

                    Cursor mCursor2 = bd.rawQuery(query, null);

                    try {

                        if (mCursor2.getCount() > 0) {

                            if (mCursor2.moveToFirst()) {
                                do {

                                    TelefoneModel mTelefoneModel = new TelefoneModel();    
                                    mTelefoneModel.setTelefones_id(mCursor2.getInt(mCursor2.getColumnIndex(TelefoneModel.Coluna.TELEFONES_ID)));
                                    mTelefoneModel.setId_rm(mCursor2.getInt(mCursor2.getColumnIndex(TelefoneModel.Coluna.ID_RM)));
                                    mTelefoneModel.setNumero(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex(TelefoneModel.Coluna.NUMERO)));
                                    mTelefoneModel.setTipo(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex(TelefoneModel.Coluna.TIPO)));
                                    mTelefoneModel.set_criado(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex(TelefoneModel.Coluna._CRIADO)));
                                    mTelefoneModel.set_modificado(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex(TelefoneModel.Coluna._MODIFICADO)));
                                    mTelefoneModel.set_status(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex(TelefoneModel.Coluna._STATUS)));
                                    listaDeRegistros.add(mTelefoneModel);
                                    System.out.println("TELEFONES AQUI " + mTelefoneModel);
                                } while (mCursor2.moveToNext());
                            }
                        }

                        return listaDeRegistros;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }while (mCursor1.moveToNext());

            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Adapter:

```
public class TelefoneViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ClienteDetalheActivity detalhe;

    private List<TelefoneModel> tele;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public TelefoneViewAdapter(Context context, ClienteDetalheActivity clienteDetalhe, List<TelefoneModel> telefone) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        this.tele = telefone;

        detalhe = clienteDetalhe;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return tele.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cliente_detalhe, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.enderecoId);
            holder.numero = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.telefone);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }

        TelefoneModel item = new TelefoneModel();
        item = tele.get(position);

        holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTelefones_id()));
        holder.numero.setText(item.getNumero());


        return vi;
    }


    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView id;
        TextView numero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put Log in your while loop and see if looping more than once.

Comment: I don't really see any code where you loop through the list and print the item out one by one

Comment: `listaDeRegistros` is a list of phones. Not just "one" phone"

Comment: @PedroOliveira yes, it is a list of phones, I said that I have 3 phones in that list

Comment: @Chitrang how can I do that?

Comment: System.out.println("check = " + mCursor2.getInt(mCursor2.getColumnIndex(TelefoneModel.Coluna.TELEFONES_ID)));


See how many time this print in your while loop.

Comment: check is printed one time only write? That means your loop iterated  one time only. So might be some thing wrong with your query.

Comment: @Chitrang yes it printed only once, what might be wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing an object that contains multiple objects.

From what I've seen you are trying to print a list of phones. But remember that you can't just print the `list.toString()` because that will only print one item. The list itself. If you want to print all the phones you have to iterate the list and print it's containers one by one. You can archive that by doing a simple `for each`

```
for(TelefoneModel phone : listaDeRegistros)
    System.out.println("Phone " + phone);
```

Replace your `System.out.println` for this line and you it'll iterate all the phones within your list and print them.

**EDIT**

Also remember that your code is only using the first element of `mCursor1`. If this returns more than one object and you want to get the phones for that cursor too you have to do a `do/while` for this cursor, just like you did for the phones. Otherwise your code looks like this -> "Get all address with id=3 -> Get all the phones with the id of the first item in addresses.

Comment: Thank you for your help Pedro, but I did as you said, and the results are still the same, look: `10-03 16:02:46.229  15894-15894/br.com. I/System.out﹕ Phone br.com.database.models.TelefoneModel@422e42b8`

Comment: Ok, Pedro, I've added the `do/while` in the mCursor1, but still the same results...

Comment: Remove the `List<TelefoneModel> listaDeRegistros = new ArrayList<TelefoneModel>();` from the `do/while` and put it outside. Otherwise you are creating a new list everytime

Comment: Remove the `return listaDeRegistros` from the inner loop. Friend.. You need to pay attention to your code.